# GCM registration id null

Tags: javascript, java, cordova

i am getting a gcm registration id which is null when using local database. I run this version of my cordova app with the servlets on my local machine. My app is in the playstore and it was working fine on my device meaning it was able to get a registration id. However when i use servlets on my local machine, it says gcm registration id is null. I am confused as to how google will generate gcm registration id with app in store and with my local database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the call to firebase to get registration id. After i had put it i got the registration id.

```
var push = PushNotification.init({
       "android": {
           "senderID": 
       },
       "ios": {
         "sound": true,
         "alert": true,
         "badge": true
       },
       "windows": {}
   });

push.on('registration', function(data) {
       console.log("registration event: " + data.registrationId);
       localStorage.setItem('registrationId', data.registrationId);
   });

push.on('error', function(e) {
       console.log("push error = " + e.message);
   });

push.on('notification', function(data) {
         console.log('notification event');
         navigator.notification.alert(
             data.message,         // message
             null,                 // callback
             data.title,           // title
             'Ok'                  // buttonName
         );

 push.finish(function() {
             console.log('success');
         }, function() {
             console.log('error');
         });
     });
```